# CCRC CLI lsactivity command

Tags: command-line-interface, clearcase-remote-client

I have installed [CCRC 7.1.1 with CLI](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21205629). I was trying to get the list of activities using `rcleartool` command bit I could not find `lsactivity` command.
Is there any equivalent command or any indirect way to achieve this targetM

Also there is no `-fmt` option for "`rcleartool desc`" command?
This was a very useful option in UCM but could not find in CCRC. Please help me with equivalent command in CCRC.

Thanks,
Raghav

Answer (score 1):

The commands supported by rcleartool are [listed here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24021929).
They don't include `lsact`.

A potential workaround (not tested) would be to use **`describe -fmt`**. (see [fmt_ccase](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm), and the [`describe` command](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm))

```
rcleatool descr -fmt "%[activities]CXp" aStream@\aPVob
```

([supported only in CCRC 9.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56556211/6309))

That should list all activities for a given stream.
I doubt however it can work, because, even though `-fmt` seems supported (because not listed in the limitations)...

> The following limitations affect `rcleartool describe`:
>
> - Version-extended pathnames are not supported
> - **UCM object selectors are not supported**
> - The following Base ClearCase object selectors are not supported: trigger-type, pool, hlink-type, oid-obj

If that is true for CCRC 7.1.1, then there is no workaround for now.

---

Actually:

- The [OP Raghava Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1138215/raghava-reddy) reports that `-fmt` itself isn't supported (as he indicated originally in his question) in 2012. It is supported in 2019.

```
    rcleartool desc command  
    CRCLI1022E Unrecognised option: "-fmt". 
    Usage: desc/ribe [-username user-name][-ser/ver server-url][-pas/sword user-password] 
                     [-l/ong | -s/hort] [-ala/bel {label-type-selector[,...] | -all}]
                     [-aat/tr {attr-type-selector[,...] | -all}] 
                     [-ahl/ink {hlink-type-selector[,...] | -all}] 
                     { [-cvi/ew] [-pre/decessor] pname ... | 
                       -type type-selector ... | -cact | object_selector ...}
```

- The [CCRC help page on `lsact`](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccteam_ucm_lsact.htm) only mentions the GUI, no CLI alternatives:

> To browse existing activities in the ClearCase UCM Activities view,
>
> - click the [image: UCM activities] UCM activities icon My Activities item of a UCM ClearCase view in the ClearCase Navigator,
> - or double-click the My Activities item in a ClearCase Details view.
>
> The ClearCase UCM Activities view opens and displays a list of your activities in the stream.

Comment: There is no -fmt option for "rcleartool desc" command. CRCLI1022E Unrecognised option: "-fmt".
Usage: desc/ribe [-username user-name][-ser/ver server-url][-pas/sword user-password]
                 [-l/ong | -s/hort]
                 [-ala/bel {label-type-selector[,...] | -all}]
                 [-aat/tr {attr-type-selector[,...] | -all}]
                 [-ahl/ink {hlink-type-selector[,...] | -all}]
                 { [-cvi/ew] [-pre/decessor] pname ...
                 | -type type-selector ...
                 | -cact | object_selector ...}

Comment: @RaghavaReddy: ok, the doc wasn't clear on that point. So I don't see other workaround right now. I will keep looking though.

Comment: @RaghavaReddy: I have edited my answer to include your comment, and to point to the official CCRC lsact doc... which only mentions the GUI, no CLI commands.

Answer (score 0):

I see -fmt option supported by rcleartool desc command (CCRC version 9.0.0):

```
path/to/my/vob>rcleartool desc -fmt
    CRCLI2037E "-fmt" must be specified.
    Usage: des/cribe [-l/ong | -s/hort | -fmt fmt-string]
            [-ala/bel {label-type-selector[,...] | -all} ]
            [-aat/tr {attr-type-selector[,...] | -all} ]
            [-ahl/ink {hlink-type-selector[,...] | -all}
            { [-cvi/ew] [-pre/decessor] pname ... | -type type-selector ... | -cac/t | object-selector ...}
```