# rcleartool lsactivity does not have -fmt option

Tags: cleartool, clearcase-remote-client

I have a script which needs to use cleartool lsactivity -fmt command:

```
$ctoolcmd = "cleartool lsactivity -fmt \"%[headline]p\" $newactivity";
$newheadline = `$ctoolcmd`;
```

Unfortunately, I am using CCRC and hence it does not support '-fmt' for 'lsactivity' command. 
Is there any other way I can achieve the same result with rcleartool command?

Comment: You still have not validated answers to past questions (but are asking new questions): please take time to review your past questions first.

Comment: (I meant not  just this question or just my answers: others have helped you)

Comment: Answers will get upvote or will be accepted if it solves the problem. Its not fair to link between the num of questions asked and the num of accepted answers :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might then need to use [`cleartool describe`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_describe.htm) instead of `lsactivity`.
Note: `rcleartool` does not support UCM object selectors, [as I mentioned in 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8785778/6309).

`-fmt` might not be supported with `describe` as well, but you could grep its output in order to extract the headline.

Test if a `rcleartool describe activityName@\aPVob` yields enough in its output, or if the `activity:` UCM selector is required (in which case, again, `rcleartool` would not support it)

That should work: the documentation mentions:

> ### UCM objects
>
> Provides information on UCM objects: activities, baselines, components, folders, projects, and streams.
>
> This form of the command displays information similar to that displayed by the UCM commands `lsactivity –long`, `lsbl –long`, `lscomp –long`, `lsfolder –long`, `lsproject –long`, and `lsstream –long`.

An `lsact -long` (which you can achieve with `rcleartool describe anActivity@\aPvob`) should include the headline, but again, you will have to parse and extract it from the output of this command.